# How to draw an axvline with arrow head?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'd like to add to a plot an `axvline` at a specific data coordinate that terminates with an arrow head (and choose either an upward pointing arrow that terminates at the top of the plot or a downward pointing arrow that terminates at the bottom of the plot, or both).

e.g.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot([1,2,3])
ax.axvline(1.5, arrow_head=[True,False])
```

would give a vertical line with an arrow head on the bottom, but none on the top (i.e. a downward pointing arrow).

I don't see a way to do this directly within `axvline`, but I can get most of the way there with `ax.arrow()` and a Blended Transformation (data coordinates for x and axis coordinates for y):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.transforms as transforms

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot([1,2,3],[1,4,9])

mytrans = transforms.blended_transform_factory(ax.transData, ax.transAxes)
ax.arrow(2.5,0,0,1,transform=mytrans,head_width=0.1,length_includes_head=True)
```

[image: image of output of axvline-as-arrow]

My questions:
1) is there an easier/cleaner way to do this?
2) how would you make a double-headed arrow this way?

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled over the same problem and think there is still no direct way to do this with `ax.axvline()` or `ax.arrow()`.
As a workaround which enables double-ended arrows (and much more) I used

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import FancyArrowPatch

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot([1, 2, 3], [1, 4, 9])

x = 2.5
y1, y2 = ax.get_ybound()
myArrow = FancyArrowPatch(posA=(x, y1), posB=(x, y2), arrowstyle='<|-|>', color='0.5',
                          mutation_scale=20, shrinkA=0, shrinkB=0)
ax.add_artist(myArrow)
plt.show()
```

Which gives the following output:
[image: arrow example]